# Написать функцию которая возвращает True, если символ, полученный функцией в качестве аргумента, является согласной

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Написать функцию Sogl, которая возвращает True, если символ, полученный функцией в качестве аргумента, является согласной буквой русского алфавита и False, если буква гласная.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Sogl(char n) {
    int k = true;
    char mas[11] = { 'а', 'у', 'о', 'ы', 'и', 'э', 'я', 'ю', 'ё', 'е' };
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (n == mas[i])
            k=false;
    }
        return k;
}

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    char n;
    cout << "Введите букву: "; cin >> n;
    if (Sogl(n) == false) 
        cout << "Буква гласная" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Буква согласная" << endl;
}
```

Постоянно возвращает true не пойму как исправить

Comment: А если это окажется цифра или латинская буква?... Или знак препинания?

Comment: а ``int k = true`` разве можно?

Comment: @Эникейщик В принципе можно, неявное преобразование...

Answer (score 1):

вместо `setlocale(LC_ALL,"ru)` нужно написать

```
SetConsoleCP( 1251 );
SetConsoleOutputCP( 1251 );

и не забыть #include <windows.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

То, *что вы хотите*, делается заменой

```
if (n == mas[i]) k=false;
```

на

```
if (n == mas[i]) return false;
```

Comment: в таком случае она возвращает false только если ввести букву ю, в остальных случаях true

Comment: Ну, не верите - не надо. Откуда мне знать, может, у вас исходник вообще в utf-8 :)  Могу записать видео с экрана, что все работает.